# Can some group $G$ have an infinite number of cosets?

Tags: group-theory

My textbook states the number of cosets of $H$ in a finite group $G$ is $|G|/|H|$, however Is it possible for a group $G$ to have a subgroup $H$ such that $gH$ has infinite cardinality? I can't think of any examples.

Edit, a more concise way of putting it is,
is there any $H\le G$ s.t. $|G/H|$ is infinite?

Comment: Some adjustements: 1) The number of cosets is $|G|/|H|$, not $|H|/|G|$ for finite groups $G$ with subgroup $H$. -- 2) There are 4 cosets of the subgroup $4\Bbb Z$ of $\Bbb Z$, whereas $Z_4$ is the set (in fact, group) of cosets (aka. quotient gtoup). -- 3) The cardinality of $gH$ equals the cardinality of $H$ and is in general different from the number of cosets

Comment: You're absolutely right @HagenvonEitzen Apologies for the sloppiness!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. $G= \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ and $H=\mathbb Z \times  \{ 0 \}$ for example.

Answer (score 2):

There are infinitely many cosets of $\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb Q$ (when the operation is addition).

Answer (score 0):

If the group is the real numbers together with the addition operation and $H$ is the subgroup of integers, then the cardinality of $\{g\circ H | g\in G\}=\{g + H | g\in \mathbb R\}$ is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting fact about the [Prüfer $p$-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$: if $H$ is a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$, then
$$
\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)/H\cong \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)
$$
However, all proper subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ are finite.

For other examples, consider $V$ a two-dimensional vector space over an infinite field and $U$ a one-dimensional subspace; then $U$ is infinite and $V/U$ is infinite as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the Euclidean plane with vector addition a line through the origin is a subgroup. Its cosets are the lines parallel to that line.